# Question about Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

It is known that a man-in-the-middle attack on the Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol in which the adversary generates two public-private key pairs for the attack. Could the same attack be accomplished with one pair? Thank you.

Comment: This might be better suited to the Cryptography stack exchange, since it's about the key exchange algorithm itself much more than it's about the way an attacker uses it. I *think* that reusing the same DH parameters for both other parties works fine, though.

Comment: Yes, there won't be any difference.